# Given $f(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+r_4(x)$, find for what values of $x$ absolute error

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Find for what values of $x$ in this formula absolute error will be no bigger than $0.0001$
$$\cos x \approx 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$$

$$\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+r_4(x).$$

I want to write $r_4(x)$ using Lagrange remainder:

$$r_4(x)=\frac{d^3 f}{dx^3} \frac{x^4}{4!}$$

from here $$\frac{\sin(c)c^4}{24} \leq 0.0001$$

from here $c$ $\leq$ $\frac{\sqrt[4]{24}}{10}$.

but answer is $|c|$ $\leq$ $\frac{\sqrt[4]{24}}{10}$.

Comment: Note that the cosine is an even function. Also, you have to thake the $4$th derivative in $r_4$.

Comment: You can't "square root" an inequality. In general $x^2 \le a \implies |x| \le \sqrt{a}$ assuming $a \ge 0$.